# How to add the results of iterating over an array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have two methods (each outputting the same):

```
def number(array)
  array.each do |val1, val2|
    (val1 - val2)
  end
end

number([[10, 0], [3, 5], [5, 8]])
# => 10, -2, -3
```

and

```
def number(array)
  array.each do |index|
    (index[0] - index[1])
  end
end

number([[10, 0], [3, 5], [5, 8]])
# => 10, -2, -3
```

I wish to know how to find the sum of the results of the iteration. I though I can do something like:

```
(val1 - val2).sum
```

but this does not work.

Comment: Not clear why you showed two methods. Do you want to do it with either of them?

Comment: I wasn't sure which was best practice, so I was going to see what answers I might receive to indicate which method is best to use (I guess I could have just asked?) :-)

Comment: Not sure why your code uses `each` which does not return any result.  Did you mean `map`?  Your code as shown above does not give the output you have mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

The ordinary way to do that is:

```
[[10, 0], [3, 5], [5, 8]].inject(0){|sum, (val1, val2)| sum + val1 - val2}
# => 5
```

Comment: Thats great - thanks for that! I have just looked up the .inject method, and that makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

```
[[10, 0], [3, 5], [5, 8]].map{|elem| elem[0] - elem[1]}.inject{|sum,elem| sum + elem}
```

Comment: You could also use `map{|e1, e2| e1 - e2 }`

Answer (score 1):

This answer is same as other answers, just uses a different syntax.

```
[[10, 0], [3, 5], [5, 8]].map { |a| a.reduce(:-) }.reduce(:+)
```

Comment: It's more or less the same as @msergeant's answer, but not @sawa's. Your code iterates over the data twice (not counting the inner `inject`); @sawa's does only once.